# changing import name in python

Tags: python, django, import

is it possible to change the name of the imported python file?

in my views.py in django i have

```
from myapp.models import *
from suds.client import Client

def main_page(request, id):
   client = Client.objects.get(id=id)
     ...
   response = Client(WSDL_FILE)
     ...
```

in my models i have a model of a Client, but when i used `suds` for the `WSDL` file,
i import Client but i got the AttributeError in my Client's model ...

my question is, it is possible if i can change the name of the `Client` in `suds.client`?

can anyone have an idea about my situation?

thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can use `as` keyword.

```
import my_module as some_other_name
from suds.client import Client as Spam
```

It's for exactly this purpose.  This is explained in the docs here:

http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#import

Answer (score 4):

```
from suds.client import Client as WhateverYouLike
```