# Module longname and shortname

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [changing import name in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997274/changing-import-name-in-python)

In Pymel,

when i access a class name Transform which is inside a module name nodetypes. I can accss the class in two following ways.

1. LongName:- nodetypes.Transform
2. ShortName:- nt.Transform

how can i do this with my own created modules.

Kindly explain.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import nodetypes as nt
```

...and you're done.

Comment: No, if i import nodetypes as nt, then i cant access the module as nodetypes but as nt.

Comment: Well, then just do both. Add `import nodetypes` as the next line. But what's the point?

Comment: yes, i imported both then. 
in pymel u can access both ways.